# Image isn't showing up in sql server database after sending image to it from MVC WCF service

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, image, wcf

I send the image from a Windows Phone 8 App to an MVC WCF service. I know it is receiving the image, because when it does receive the image, it is instructed to save the image in a local folder called "uploads". Every time the image gets there it is put into this folder so I can tell that it was uploaded. My trouble is with uploading it to my SQL Server database. Everything compiles, but when I check my database table, it is not there. Please help.

```
namespace MVCImageUpload.Controllers
{
 public class FileUploadController : Controller
 {
    // GET: /FileUpload/ 
    [HttpPost]    
    public ActionResult Index()  
    { 
        var fileUploaded = false; 
        foreach (string upload in Request.Files)    
        {            
            if (!HasFile(Request.Files[upload])) 
                continue;
            string path = Path.Combine(
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
                "uploads");
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(
                Request.Files[upload].FileName); 
            if (!Directory.Exists(path)) 
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path); 
            Request.Files[upload].SaveAs(Path.Combine(
                path, filename));
            fileUploaded = true;

            updatedata(filename);
        } 

        this.ViewData.Add("uploaded", fileUploaded); 
        return View(); 
    } 
    private static bool HasFile(HttpPostedFileBase file) 
    { 
        return (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) ? true : false; 
    }

    private void updatedata(string imagename)   
    {      
        //use filestream object to read the image.  
        //read to the full length of image to a byte array.     
        //add this byte as an oracle parameter and insert it into database.    
        try     
        {         
            //proceed only when the image has a valid path       
            if (imagename != "")    
            {                
                FileStream fs;          
                fs = new FileStream(@imagename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);  
                //a byte array to read the image     
                byte[] picbyte = new byte[fs.Length];   
                fs.Read(picbyte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));       
                fs.Close();           
                //open the database using odp.net and insert the data       
                string connstr = @".\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ImageDB;Trusted_Connection=True;";         
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);         
                conn.Open();            
                string query;            
                query = "insert into Images(ActualImage) values(@ActualImage)";  
                SqlParameter picparameter = new SqlParameter();       
                picparameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;           
                picparameter.ParameterName = "ActualImage";               
                picparameter.Value = picbyte;           
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);      
                cmd.Parameters.Add(picparameter);              
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();             
              //MessageBox.Show("Image Added");        
                cmd.Dispose();               
                conn.Close();             
                conn.Dispose();             
                //Connection();          
            }     
        }        
        catch (Exception ex)    
        {      
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);     
        }    
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: You need to put some code into your global `catch` and see what exception happens..... right now, you're just swallowing it without logging or showing anything - so whatever exception might be occurring, you don't know about it.....

Comment: I did what you said and this is what I came up with:

   at MVCImageUpload.Controllers.FileUploadController.updatedata(String imagename) in c:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MVCImageUpload\Controllers\FileUploadController.cs:line 57'

                       Line 57:

 fs = new FileStream(@imagename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 

Any Idea?

Comment: Obviously, the file cannot be uploaded - but what you're showing is just part of the stack trace -not the *whole* error message.... hard to say without the **complete** and accurate error message!

Comment: Sorry about that, I asked a new question, which includes of the exception details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019178/filestream-exception-while-using-image

Answer (score 0):

You can skip a step and save the file directly into the database.

```
                HttpPostedFileBase Picture = Request.Files["Picture"];
                Byte[] Bytes = new byte[Picture.ContentLength];
                string ContentType = Picture.ContentType;
                string FileName = Picture.FileName;
                Picture.InputStream.Read(Bytes, 0, Picture.ContentLength);
```

You now have Name, Bytes, and content type which u can store in the database.

Comment: I tried your idea out and it is giving me this error:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.         At this line of code:

                        Byte[] Bytes = new byte[Picture.ContentLength];

Comment: If you set a breakpoint after picture variable you can see if Picture is NULL. If it is NULL that means you are not posting the picture with the "name=Picture". Request.Files function must be called inside the controller method.